# Using jquery disable button till input has been entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am somewhat of a jQuery noob but I have managed to get where I need to go bar one edit.

So from a dropdown list if one of the last 2 options are selected it shows and input field asking why the user rated the service so low. This works fine. However, I need to make these fields required if they are shown.

Keep in mind there are multiple fields.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
 
    $('.csv-four-wrap').hide();
    $('.csv-five-wrap').hide(); 
    
    
    
    
 $(function()
    {
      $('#ninja_forms_field_18').change(function()
      {
      console.log( $(this).attr('value') );
        if ( $(this).attr('value') == '5' || $(this).attr('value') == '4' || $(this).attr('value') == '3') {
           $('.csv-four-wrap').hide('fast');
        }
        if ( $(this).attr('value') == '2') {
           $('.csv-four-wrap').show('fast');
           $('.csv-four-wrap label').text('Please comment why we are below expectations');
        }  
        if ( $(this).attr('value') == '1') {
           $('.csv-four-wrap').show('fast');
           $('.csv-four-wrap label').text('Please comment why you are not satisfied');
        }   
      });
}); 
 $(function()
    {
      $('#ninja_forms_field_19').change(function()
      {
      console.log( $(this).attr('value') );
        if ( $(this).attr('value') == '5' || $(this).attr('value') == '4' || $(this).attr('value') == '3') {
           $('.csv-five-wrap').hide('fast');
        }
        if ( $(this).attr('value') == '2') {
           $('.csv-five-wrap').show('fast');
           $('.csv-five-wrap label').text('Please comment why we are below expectations');
        }  
        if ( $(this).attr('value') == '1') {
           $('.csv-five-wrap').show('fast');
           $('.csv-five-wrap label').text('Please comment why you are not satisfied');
        }   
      });
}); 


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
$('.csv-four-wrap').find("input, select, textarea").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("required", "true");
}});
```

After `$('.csv-four-wrap').show('fast');`

Edit: Do the same for "csv-five-wrap"

Comment: Note: the `required` attribute is only supported by IE > 9

Comment: THANKS! This is perfect!